# Finding if all properties within a class are the same

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple class that contains 4 double properties like this

```
 public MyClass
 {
     public MyClass(double all = 0)
     {
         Top = Bottom = Left = Right = all;
     }
     public MyClass(double lr = 0, double tb = 0)
     {
         Top = Bottom = tb;
         Left = Right = lr;
     }
     public MyClass(double l = 0, double r = 0, double t = 0, double b = 0)
     {
         Top = t;Bottom = b;Left = l;Right = r;
     }

     public double Top {get; private set;}
     public double Bottom {get; private set;}
     public double Left {get; private set;}
     public double Right {get; private set;}
}
```

Is there a simple way to check if all the properties have the same value? I'd rather not use `if (Top == Bottom) && (Top == Left) ...` as it's somewhat messy IMHO. Can it be done in LINQ?

Comment: Why would "doing exactly what you want to do" be messy? Any other solution, especially when adding LINQ, will only become more messy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ works on collections. You don't have a collection, you have four separate properties.

Anything you're going to do to force this into LINQ is only going to make it more messy.

Just use plain old C#:

```
public bool AllPositionsEqual
{
    get
    {
        return Top == Bottom 
            && Left == Right
            && Left == Top;
    }
}
```

This is clear to you now, and clear to another reader when they read it, and clear to you when you read it in a few months.

If you're going to stuff the properties in a collection just to be able to call a LINQ method on it in order to determine they are all the same, you *are* breaking the "principle of least astonishment". The reader of that code *will* go "WTF".

If, instead, you want to be able to do this on an arbitrary class (which would also be a really confusing requirement), you can do it as such:

- Get all properties using reflection
- Get all properties' values for this instance in a collection
- On this collection, call `Distinct()`.

*Then* you'll have a legitimate use case for LINQ. Right now, you haven't.

Answer (score 5):

You can insert them into a `HashSet<double>`:

```
var doubles = new HashSet<double> { Top, Left, Right, Bottom };
if (doubles.Count == 1)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Or use `Enumerable.Distinct`:

```
var doubles = new[] { Top, Bottom, Left, Right };
if (doubles.Distinct().Count() == 1)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

But perhaps the most simple approach is to create a method (or a property, if you fancy that):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool AreAllPropertiesSame()
    {
        return Top == Bottom && Left == Top && Right == Left;
    }
}
```

Note any use of LINQ will incur more overhead then doing a simply `if` check on 4 properties. I would definitely go with a simple property or method approach which is clear and concise. Don't defer to LINQ because you can, use it because it is the best tool for the job, where clearly here it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

To underline what @CodeCaster already mentioned concerning the messyness the following would be the appropriate code for that:

```
var properties = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties();
var first = proerties[0].GetValue(myInstance, null);
if (properties.Select(x => x.GetValue(myInstance, null)).All(x => x.Equals(first)) 
{ 
    /* ... */ 
}
```

This checks for all properties within your type `MyClass` by reflection. However everything is better than this approach, only added it for completeness. If you want it some stable you´d at least have to also prove if the class actually has any properties.

This only applies for non-indexed properties. If your property is indexed you´ll also have to prove for every element also which gets much dirtier.

Now compare this to the really nice and short `Top == Bottom && Left == Top && Right == Left` from @Yuval.

Comment: That ToList is redundant and can be omitted since [GetProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `PropertyInfo[]`

Answer (score 2):

Im really a big fan of writing a Method for cases like this, since it is reusable and has a name that tells whats happening here.

```
public static bool AllEqual<T>(T frist, params T[] values)
{
    return values.All(v => Equal(first,v));
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
ObjectHelper.AllEqual(Top, Bottom, Left, Right);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
bool b = (Top == (new double[] { Top, Bottom, Left, Right }).Average());
```

This could be an alternative workaround?

Dom

Comment: This not true, if `Top =1, Bottom = -1 Left =2,  Right = 2`  average would be 1 which equals Top....